# Counter occurrences within the same item in python

Tags: python, group-by, counter

Sorry, I'm pretty sure that somebody else may have asked this question already but I did not find it. I'd like to keep track the number of times I've seen this specific item like

Input :

```
[88,88,27,0,88]
```

Desired Output :

```
[1,2,1,1,3]
```

I'm looking for something especially good in terms of performance.
I'm ok with Numpy or Pandas solutions.

Comment: Why is that your desired output?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-to-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item).

Comment: The first item of the desired output means that it is the first time I've seen the "8"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst = [8,1,2,3,1,3,3,1,2,99]

cnt = {}
res = []

for x in lst:
    cnt[x] = cnt.get(x,0)+1
    res += [cnt[x]]

print(res)
```

Output

Comment: Thks for your answer. Do you know any implementation with Numpy?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way using a list comprehension:

```
x = [8,1,2,3,1,3,3,1,2,99]
y = [x[:i].count(el) + 1 for i, el in enumerate(x)]
print(y)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: This can be solved in a single pass though, no slices, no repeated counting.

Comment: Thks for your answer but it seems very costly to do it

Comment: I would agree with you, really just depends on the input size you are dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
... 
... 
... def solution(lst):
...     result = []
...     seen = defaultdict(int)
...     for num in lst:
...         seen[num] += 1
...         result.append(seen[num])
...     return result
... 
>>> solution([88, 88, 27, 0, 88])
[1, 2, 1, 1, 3]
>>> solution([8, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 99])
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]
```

Without imports:

```
>>> def solution(lst):
...     result = []
...     seen = {}
...     for num in lst:
...         try:
...             seen[num] += 1
...         except KeyError:
...             seen[num] = 1
...         result.append(seen[num])
...     return result
... 
>>> solution([88, 88, 27, 0, 88])
[1, 2, 1, 1, 3]
>>> solution([8, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 99])
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Thks for your answer But I would prefer not importing this collection library

Answer (score 1):

one with generators:

```
def return_count(l):
    cnt = {}
    for x in l:
        cnt[x] = cnt.get(x, 0) + 1
        yield cnt[x]

print(list(return_count([8, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 99])))
```